# Python/Selenium Firefox Driver Fails On Ubuntu, Fine On Windows

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, geckodriver

I have the following installed on Ubuntu (Amazon EC2 t2.small):
geckodriver: `0.24.0`
firefox: `68.0.1`
selenium: `3.141.0`

On Windows, I have:
geckodriver: `0.24.0`
firefox: `67.0.4`
selenium: `3.141.0`

I don't know if the differing firefox versions are the problem, but I'm having trouble downloading 67.0.4 on Ubuntu (following [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/661186/how-to-install-previous-firefox-version)). I get the extracted firefox folder to /usr/bin/firefox but when I run `firefox -v` it gives me `Command 'firefox' not found`, but that's another issue.

I'm running the following block of code:

```py
share_url =  ( driver.current_url )

...code here...

# scroll down a couple times
for _ in range(4):
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    time.sleep(1)
```

The logic is the exact same across versions. It was also working earlier.

This fails on Ubuntu with the below errors, and works just fine on Windows.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/cashmuny/tiktok/main.py", line 882, in <module>
    compilationBody(language_code, directory, clips, len(channels.channels[language_code]), 45, record_ids, get_vids = g
et_vids, min_video_size=min_video_size, headless=headless_compilation)
  File "/home/ubuntu/cashmuny/tiktok/main.py", line 448, in compilationBody
    getMediaClips(channels.LANG_TO_COUNTRY[language_code], directory, clip[0], clip[1], record_ids, min_video_size, head
less=headless)
  File "/home/ubuntu/cashmuny/tiktok/main.py", line 353, in getMediaClips
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 636, in execute_sc
ript
    'args': converted_args})['value']
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_r
esponse
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchWindowException: Message: Browsing context has been discarded
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/cashmuny/tiktok/main.py", line 844, in <module>
    compilationBody(language_code, directory, clips, len(channels.channels[language_code]), 45, record_ids, get_vids = get_vids, min_video_size=min_video_size)
  File "/home/ubuntu/cashmuny/tiktok/main.py", line 427, in compilationBody
    getMediaClips(channels.LANG_TO_COUNTRY[language_code], directory, clip[0], clip[1], record_ids, min_video_size)
  File "/home/ubuntu/cashmuny/tiktok/main.py", line 283, in getMediaClips
    share_url =  ( driver.current_url )
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 669, in current_url
    return self.execute(Command.GET_CURRENT_URL)['value']
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
**selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Failed to decode response from marionette**
```

Comment: Does this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54525301/browsing-context-has-been-discarded-using-geckodriver-firefox-through-selenium/54529774#54529774)  helps you?

Answer (score 0):

My experience has been that Selenium is *very* sensitive to the version of browser it is running against. I would definitely try to work through whatever issues you're having getting 67.0.4 installed as I'm fairly certain that will get you going again.